# Visualising variance from random effects in a mixed model by group

Tags: r, graphics, lme4, mixed-models

I have run a linear mixed model in R using lmer. I am attempting to visualise the random effect structure. To produce a graph I have used `print(dotplot(ranef(RT.model.4, condVar=T))[['part_no']])` where `part_no` is the random effect from the mixed model. It creates something like this:

[image]

This is great. However I want to be able to visually tell the difference between my two groups of participants (the random effect being discussed) in the graph. I have group A and group B. In my dataset I have a column for participant type and for each row it gives a value of A or B.

I would like to either colour code the graph to show participants from groups A and B. Or perhaps better would be to create two separate panels, one for each group.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It might be useful to provide a (small) representative sample dataset.

Answer (score 4):

This is a way using `ggplot` rather than `lattice` (just because I am more familiar with it) using code from the examples in `?dotplot.ranef.mer`. You need to match your *treatment group* in the data to the random effects grouping variables returned by `ranef`. I don't see how this can be done automatically within `dotplot.ranef.mer`.

Create a small example with a treatment group; each subject is assigned to one treatment group.

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

sleepstudy$trt = as.integer(sleepstudy$Subject %in% 308:340)

m = lmer(Reaction ~  trt + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Convert the random effects to a dataframe and match in the treatment groups

```
dd = as.data.frame(ranef(m, condVar=TRUE), "Subject")
dd$trt = with(sleepstudy, trt[match(dd$grp, Subject)])
```

You can then plot how you want, say using `facet_`'s or assigning a colour to each group, or ...

```
ggplot(dd, aes(y=grp,x=condval, colour=factor(trt))) +
        geom_point() + facet_wrap(~term,scales="free_x") +
        geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=condval -2*condsd,
                           xmax=condval +2*condsd), height=0)

ggplot(dd, aes(y=grp,x=condval)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=condval -2*condsd,
                           xmax=condval +2*condsd), height=0)+
        facet_wrap(~trt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `groups=` option in `dotplot()`. Assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df` with the group variable being in `group`, you could use

```
print(dotplot(ranef(RT.model.4, condVar=T), groups=df$group)[['part_no']])
```